# Convert Tableau expression to SSRS

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012, tableau-desktop

I need to convert Tableau expression to SSRS expression. How that gonna looks like in SSRS?

```
IF(sum(IF [Column1] = "Yes"
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END))>0
THEN'Yes'
ELSE'No'
END
```

Comment: You could first convert it to more compact Tableau to simplify, say max([Column 1] = “Yes”) - does effectively the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:
=IIF(sum(IIF(([Column1] = "Yes"),1,0))>0,"Yes","No")